# How to inspect nullable types strict code smell

Tags: php, phpstorm, php-7, strict

I'm converting a Symfony 3.4 project to fully use PHP 7's strict types. It feels really nice like doing in normal stricter programming languages.

I noticed something very misconceiving in the convertion process tho. Let's say in other programming languages you have:

```
*string == nil (valid)
*string == string (invalid)
*string == *int (invalid)
```

In PHP you have:

```
?string == null (valid)
?string == string (valid)
?string == ?int (valid)
```

This last `?string == ?whatever` is what now remains after adding all the strictness to parameters and method return values. The issue is that the code now contains tons of bombs of code smell, which already caused me tons of unexpected errors in development mode.

I know it's not really possible because PHP has no knowledge of pointer-types themselves, but I was wondering if there's a PHPStorm plugin, or something in general that can actually find these possible code smells.

So it would match `?string == ?int` as faulty (error level), whereas `?string == null` is still ok. And something like `?string > string` (moving from nullable into only `string` could be faulty (warning level).

I can't be the only person that has encountered this problem. As the project that I'm converting is massive and didn't had tests written with them in the past It's really just hoping that testing all paths (literal browsing) in the application will catch most of the standard clashes, but you can just predict that there's a big probability in data-variance that it will throw some errors when the production version is getting all code paths walked with ton of data-variance.

**Update**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

class SaleOrder
{
    private $price;
    private $fee;
    private $number;

    public function setPrice(?float $price): self
    {
        $this->price = $price;
        return $this;
    }
}

function generateStringedPrice(): ?string
{
    return '420.00';
}

function generateStringedNulledPrice(): ?string
{
    return null;
}

$price = 420.0;
$priceNulled = null;
$priceString = generateStringedPrice();
$priceStringNulled = generateStringedNulledPrice();

$order = new SaleOrder();
$order->setPrice($price);           // OK
$order->setPrice($priceNulled);     // OK
$order->setPrice($priceString);     // Fatal, but not seen by PHPStorm because null fits in null, but it doesn't "smell" that when it knows `?float` and `?string` are in play it could give a warning that when `?string` is not null, it might cause a fatal (which it does, but you can't instantly detect it with different data flowing through the code from different sources)
$order->setPrice($priceStringNulled); // OK, it doesn't care ?float and ?string were in play; null is null; no one cares :P
```

Comment: Could you please attach a code sample of such a code smell bomb?

Comment: @Ástþór Thanks for the reply! I've added some simpified code. It's mainly about the story in the 3rd setPrice call where the comment says Fatal. I wish I could run the PHP Inspection in such a way that it could warn me about ?float and ?string potentially giving type errors.

Comment: That's a great example, thanks. PhpStorm is indeed not giving you a warning here. You can add this example in a comment at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32159 or I can do that for you.

Comment: Thank you! I've added the info to the ticket. Seeing the issue is so old, can it be expected to ever being picked up? Otherwise I'll have to figure out something else to inspect these smells.

Comment: Yeah, it can be. But unfortunately I can't provide any estimates